# Mercurial: what are the consequences of changing a phase?

Tags: mercurial, phase

In Mercurial, the phase of a revision can be changed arbitrarily. What are the consequences of a phase change for all possible transitions *(public, draft, secret) x (public, draft, secret)*? Which phase changes are safe? Which may cause troubles and which kind of troubles? Which are more or less no-ops?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default phase for a commit is `draft`, that's how they were treated when the phases didn't exist. When pushing a `draft` changeset, mercurial automatically changes its phase to `public`. You can use it to know which changesets you have already published or not.

But the real issue is that when the changeset is in `public` phase, mercurial won't let you change them with history editing extensions (like `mq`, `rebase`, etc). That's really important, because the history editing happens *only* in the local repository, they don't propagate with `pull`/`push` operations. So, once a changeset is published, it's out of control, it's dangerous to change it.

You can change from any phase to any other phase. The "normal flow" is to move to a higher phase (secret->draft->public), but Mercurial allows the change to a lower phase with the `--force` option. A phase change alone is harmless. For example, the only thing that happens when moving from `public` to `draft` or `secret` is that the protection of history editing is dropped, nothing else, pull and push will still work normally, Mercurial could never be confused about the changesets because they have unique identifiers. The history editing action that takes place *after* a phase change like this is what can cause problems. And that's why Mercurial gives the warning in the phase change and requires the `--force` option, as a confirmation that that's what you really want.

In general published commits shoudn't be modified, that's what the phases try to ensure. But maybe you do have control over all repositories. Or maybe you pushed something and you know that no one else pulled it yet. Whatever is the reason, you have the option of forcing the phase of the changesets back to draft and edit them. But this edition must be done in every repository that has the changesets.

Comment: The worst thing that can happen is what always happened with mercurial versions that didn't use phases: If you edit history that has already been pushed, you create mismatches with the downstream repositories. A hassle but usually no big deal, in other words.

Comment: So the only way to get the phase to secret is via an abnormal transition? Even though draft -> secret is always safe, or is secret somehow unsafe?

Comment: @richard Draft -> secret is always safe.  I'm pretty sure the warning when making that transition counts as a bug.

Answer (score 6):

- A *public* revision can't be edited with history-editing tools (i.e. `mq`, `rebase`).
- A *secret* revision can't be pushed to another repository (it will be ignored when you give the push command, or when another repository attempts to pull).
- A *draft* revision allows both, but will automatically change to *public* if it gets pushed to another repository.

The purpose of the phase system is to prevent you from modifying a revision after you've pushed it to another repository, which is a bad idea unless you're able to delete the old version of the revision from all repositories that it's been pushed to.

All phase changes are more or less no-ops; it's just a marker to indicate what is or isn't safe to do with a revision.